# Magento admin session not working within a folder

Tags: magento, session

I am trying to use the following code to get Admin session to check whether admin is logged in or not. File created at the level of **/app** folder.

```
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));

if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setAdminLogin("1");
  echo "Admin Logged In..";
}
else
{
  echo "go away bad boy";
}
```

This code is working fine at the level of **/app**.

But when I put this file within a folder at the level of **/app**, then it works only first time.

Can I have a best solution for this issue ?

Comment: cab you please tell me where did you put this code in app folder or out of app folder???

Comment: Not within app folder. It is out of app folder similar like index.php.

Comment: Hello Anx, I tested this code on my local and its working fine like http://127.0.0.1/magento1702/session.php.

Comment: Now try this - 127.0.0.1/magento1702/test/session.php. After creating **test** folder and put session.php in it. Also don't forget to change the path of **Mage.php**.